# How to check if the data time has the timezone offset or not?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am developing an application using Javascript. Within the code, I am receiving the `Datetime`. This Datetime can have the timezone offset or not. I would like to check if the timezone offset is present or not based on which I need to make a few decisions.

Following is the type of data that will come into my Javascript function:

```
const dateWithoutOffset = "2022-03-01T16:23:19"
const dateWithOffset = "2022-03-01T16:23:19+01:00"

//Perform something to check for offset
if(dateWithOffset.contains(offset)){
  console.log("OFFSET is PRESENT")
}

//Perform something to check offset is not present
if(dateWithoutOffset.contains(offset)){
  console.log("OFFSET IS NOT PRESENT")
}
```

I know that I can check for length but I feel it's not the right way so thought of asking here and finding the right way to find the offset.

I tried a lot of methods and answers present within Stackoverflow but nothing seems to give me the right answer so posting here to get a correct working answer.

Comment: With a date string, it must have a final Z or a + or a - (but some standards reserve -00:00 as unknown timezone).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for the response. In my case, the DateTime is coming from the `Datetime-local` input type and it does not have the `Z` and I am adding the offset manually. I would like to add the offset only if its not present already. So I am bit confused here.

Comment: If it's always coming from the `value` property of a `datetime-local`, it will *never* have an offset or a `Z`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#local_date_and_time_strings

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Yes from `datetime-local` will not have offset so I would like to add the local timezone to it. But there are cases when I have added the data but when I come back and proceed further it's being added again which I want to avoid so I am trying to identify if datetime already has the timezone offset if so then do not want to add the offset again if not then i would like to add the offset.

Comment: It sounds like you simply need to keep the result in a second variable or field then, as not to mutate your original input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to parse the offset from these ISO date strings.

Creating a few convenience functions such as `hasOffset()` and `getUTCOffsetMinutes()` should make the problem easier to solve.

If the date has an offset, you can proceed to parse it (as below) or do something else such as displaying differently.

```js
const isoDatePattern = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\.\d+)?([+-]\d{2}:?\d{2}|Z)$/

function getOffsetStr(input) {
    const groups = input.match(isoDatePattern);
    return groups ? groups[4]: null;
}

function hasOffset(input) {
    return (!!getOffsetStr(input));
}

function getUTCOffsetMinutes(input) {
    const offset = getOffsetStr(input);
    return offset ? parseUTCOffset(offset): null;
}

function parseUTCOffset(offsetStr) {
    if (offsetStr.toUpperCase() === 'Z') {
        return 0;
    }
    const sign = offsetStr.startsWith('-') ? -1: 1;
    const hour = +offsetStr.slice(1,3);
    const min = +offsetStr.slice(-2);
    return sign * hour * 60 + min;
}

const testInputs = [
     "2010-11-06T02:19:00.250",
     "2022-03-01T16:23:19",
     "2025-04-20T17:02:03.401+0200",
     "2022-03-01T16:23:19+01:00",
     "2022-03-01T16:23:19Z",
     "2022-03-01T16:23:19-0500",
     "2022-03-01T16:23:19+12:00"
]

console.log('Input'.padEnd(28, ' '), 'Has Offset ' ,'UTC Offset (minutes)')
testInputs.forEach(input => { 
    console.log(input.padEnd(28, ' '), hasOffset(input), '\t', getUTCOffsetMinutes(input));
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: It would be handy to also handle optional decimal seconds (milliseconds). :-)

Comment: Good point! I'll add support for that.